# Behind the scenes of Visual Basic casting - Conversion from string to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, string, casting

While playing around doing string concatenation in VB.net, I noticed a weird runtime error when trying to concatenate a string with an integer.

Here is my fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NY4Y4V

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim t As Dictionary(Of Int32, DateTime?) = new Dictionary(Of Int32, DateTime?)
        t.Add(12345, new DateTime())
        For Each f As KeyValuePair(Of Int32, DateTime?) In t
            Console.WriteLine("Test string {" + f.Key + "}.")
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Specifically, I'm curious why the exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "Test string {" to type 'Double' is not valid.

is occurring.  I know that this is a simple fix if I explicitly convert the integer to a string:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Test string {" + f.Key.ToString() + "}.")
```

I'm just curious what is happening behind the scenes that this casting error would occur.  I am not touching doubles anywhere in my code, so I am unsure why a casting to type 'Double' would be the problem being thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator in VB is a complex beast.  It can do very [different things depending on its operands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx#Anchor_4).  In your case, it's following the 3rd row in that table:

> One expression is a numeric data type and the other is a string

Therefore:

> If **Option Strict** is **On**, then generate a compiler error.
>
> If **Option Strict** is **Off**, then implicitly convert the **String** to **Double** and add.
>
> If the **String** cannot be converted to **Double**, then throw an InvalidCastException exception.

It looks like `Option Strict` must be `Off` in your code, so it is indeed attempting to convert the `String` to a `Double`, and hence erroring.

Ideally, always use `Option Strict On` (and `Option Explicit On` - they're usually the first thing I check when I'm working with VB) - it will show up all sorts of potential runtime issues at compile time instead.

Also, if you want to guarantee string concatenation, `Option Strict` or not, you can use the [`&` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx).

Comment: `if you want to guarantee string concatenation, Option Strict or not, you can use the & operator` glad you mention this in your post. I don't know how many countless times this bites people where I work as well as some of the things I have came across. Great post!